# Responsive not working on iPhone, width too long using Media 320px doesn't work

Tags: android, ios, css, iphone

I am using a default custom skin 'GHD' folder (which is not responsive) have downloaded the blanco theme, which is under 'GHDNew' folder, This is where the style.css is based and the responsive media queries.

I am using trying to style the Iphone but cannot get the portrait to work to fit the width of the device. The width is long, I can't explain it but have a look here ghd.ecommerceit.co.uk. The Landscape is working fine.

none of the page is actually fitting, and I'm having to use margins to bring everything in but struggling. Also it's my first time trying to make it responsive. Can anyone advice what I can use to bring different elements in and make them fit according to device width? i.e. Search, Navigation, Logo, Header Links, Body etc...

I don't want to use Margins but in the interim, it's working.

Mayur

Comment: Your link www.ghd.ecommerceit.co.uk does not work, I assume you mean http://ghd.ecommerceit.co.uk

Comment: Correct your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

The (or at least one) reason this does not fit is

```
.page {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    min-width: 750px;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

in your style.css

Check out a css framework for responsive design, like [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) or pure [css](http://purecss.io/).

Comment: I  cannot see this, I just searched my style.css?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have a viewport meta tag in your header, try adding

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Comment: Hi,This is already in my head.phtml file. I can add this into my header.phtml.

Answer (score 0):

In case your example page is ghd.ecommerceit.co.uk (without www), the (or at least one) problem is

```
#wrapper {
    width: 1004px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: left;
}
```

in your all.css

Comment: Hi, I can't see the all.css in FTP folder. I can only see style.css being used. I

Comment: http://ghd.ecommerceit.co.uk/skin/frontend/default/ghd/css/all.css is linked in the head of the Gardens and Home Site, if that is what you are talking about?

Comment: Hi, actually using the ghdnew, because ghd is not responsive. We have a default magento theme 'GHD' and then downloaded Blanco to pick up Mobile Devices.